# Prove there is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, span

I would like some advice with one problem.

Let $L$ be a linear space with $\dim(L)=n$. Let $K$ be some linear subspace of $L$. I need to prove there exists a linear transformation $l: L \rightarrow L$ such that $Im(l)=K$.

My shot:

let $B=\{b_1...b_n\}$ be a basis of $L$.
let $K=\{k_1...k_s\}$ be a basis of $K$, $n>s$.
we can replaces some vectors $b_1...b_s$ with $k_1...k_s$ and $Span \ B$ won't change. Than $Im(l)=Span\{l(k_1)...l(k_s), l(b_{s+1})...l(b_n)\}$
I have no idea if it's even right or what to do next. Any hints? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You can use any ${\underline{\mbox{onto}}}$ mapping of $\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$ to $\{k_1,\dots,k_s\}$.  This will determine a linear transformation $L$ with the properties you need.

Comment: I guess I need more help. don't see how to prove it

Comment: For instance you could map $b_i$ to $k_i$ for $i=1,2,...,s$ and map any remaining $b$s to $\vec{0}$.  The image of this map would be the span of the image of the basis, which would be the span of the $k$s, which would be $K$.

Comment: Yes, got it. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

Define $l:L \to L$ by 
$$l(x) = x \text{ for } x \in K$$
$$l(x) = 0 \text{ for }x \in L \setminus K$$

Obviously $l$ is linear on $K$ and on $L \setminus K$. It remains to define $l$ on $K + (L \setminus K)$ and it is just by the linearity.